# What do I do about "No video with supported format and MIME type found"?

Tags: debian, firefox, video, mime-types, devuan

I run Devuan GNU/Linux Excalibur (i.e. Debian trixie without systemd), with Firefox v123.

Recently, I've been getting errors trying to browse content involving videos (yes, from the accursed social media sites, e.g. twitter) in browser windows. I get a gray area and the message: "No video with supported format and MIME type found".

Now, first, I'm not even told what MIME type + format combinations *were* found; how can I figure that out? And second - how can I stack up on more MIME+format combination support?

Answer (score 1):

> how can I figure that out?

Yeah, I find that annoying, as well. But you can use Firefox' "Tools"->"Page Info", there the "Media" tab, to find what was embedded. Alternatively, you can use the "Web Developer's" "Inspect Element" context menu entry to inspect the video element; modern HTML allows for several formats to be specified there, so you'd then need to inspect all URLs found that way with `ffprobe`.

> And second - how can I stack up on more MIME+format combination support?

You probably can't; you need to stick with the formats supported by devuan's firefox build.

If you choose to run your own rebuild of the debian firefox package:

1. start a debian container (`podman` is your friend, or `docker`, both used with a `-v /tmp:/dataexchange:Z` for, well, exchanging data)
2. enable the source archives in the /etc/apt/sources.list of that container
3. `mkdir download; cd download; apt-get source firefox` in the container
4. copy over the downloaded files to your devuan host
5. cd into the directory of the downloaded files on your devuan host
6. run `mk-build-deps *.dsc` to get a dependency package
7. run `sudo apt-get install ./nameofdependencypacakage.deb`
8. cd into the source directory within this directory
9. run `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -ui -d` and get a coffee, then take a friend out for dinner, and come back the next morning
10. install the new firefox problem

Step 6. might reveal dependencies that aren't available on devuan. If that's the case, you need to look at them and decide whether they make a difference to your use case, and adjust debian/RULES accordingly, or port the missing dependencies as described above (but replacing `firefox` with the package, of course).

In essence, with devuan you're choosing to go for a functional subset of modern Linux, in exchange for an ideological goal (whether I agree with that or not doesn't matter here).  It's thoroughly possible that you'll not experience the feature set of a standard Linux distro that way, I'm afraid.

Comment: Can I possibly take a shortcut by downloading an FF build from Mozilla?

Comment: @einpoklum if they have such for an niche operating system that intentionally deviates from what I'd call "the modern desktop Linux base"? Possible, but unlikely.